# Замена данных в JSON

Tags: c#, json

Наконец-то разобрался с www.newtonsoft.com , но остался один вопрос - каким способом заменить в файле данные, если они изменились?

Например, есть входной JSON:

```
{
  "76561197962584159": {
    "uid": 76561197962584159,
    "name": "TEST4"
  }
}
```

Изменился `name` и нужно его обновить

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68189/discussion-on-question-by-----json).